# XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXXX due to access control checks When using Angular Material MD Stepper

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, cors

My application worked perfectly until about an hour ago. Now I seem to be in limbo about figuring out why specific https requests are not working all browsers aside from chrome web. My first assumption is CORS. I have origin headers and everything set up as I have had for some time. Im not sure what changed.

Here is the error I am getting on Safari

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/auth/server/signup due to access control checks.

Here is my CORS middleware

```
app.use(function (req,res,next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", devUrl);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, PATCH, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```

`devUrl` is a var as the correct URL.

Here are the calls in node that are not working

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var authController = require('../controllers').auth;
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


router.post('/server/signup', function(req,res,next) {
  return authController.signup(req,res);
});

router.post('/server/signin', function(req,res,next) {
  return authController.signin(req,res);
});

router.post('/server/social-signin', function(req,res,next) {
  return authController.authSignin(req,res);
});


module.exports = router;
```

Requests are working for other http requests and the url that it states I used in the error is the same/correct url. Ive been stuck for a while now and seriously need help. I have no idea how to debug this. Also, it refreshes the page every time I attempt the request as well. Im not sure what to do.

---

The last route for social login is working?? Its only sign in and sign up that are affected

Here is my client-side code where the http requests are sent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  template: `    
    <!-- Main container -->
    <md-toolbar>
      <h5 style="margin: 0 auto;font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;">Signin</h5>
    </md-toolbar>
    <section class="section">
      <md-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" *ngIf="!loggingin" style="text-align: center; max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto">
        <md-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
          <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
            <ng-template mdStepLabel>Email</ng-template>
            <md-form-field>
              <input mdInput placeholder="Enter Email" formControlName="firstCtrl" [(ngModel)]="user.email" required>
            </md-form-field>
            <div>
              <button md-button mdStepperNext><p class="p2">NEXT</p></button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </md-step>
        <md-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
          <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
            <ng-template mdStepLabel>Password</ng-template>
            <md-form-field>
              <input type="password" mdInput placeholder="Enter Password" formControlName="secondCtrl" [(ngModel)]="user.password" required>
            </md-form-field>
            <div>
              <button md-button mdStepperPrevious><p class="p2">BACK</p></button>
              <button md-button (click)="onSignin('rent')"><p class="p2">SIGNIN</p></button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </md-step>
      </md-horizontal-stepper>

      <p style="text-align: center; font-size: x-large" *ngIf="!loggingin">signin with social</p>

      <div style="margin: 30px auto; text-align: center" *ngIf="!loggingin">
        <button md-mini-fab
                (click)="onSignin('facebook')" style="background-color: #3b5998!important;">
          <span class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size: x-large; color: white;"></span>
        </button>
        <button md-mini-fab
                (click)="onSignin('google')" style="background-color: #D84B37!important;">
          <span class="fa fa-google" style="font-size: x-large; color: white;"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </section>
    <button md-raised-button (click)="test()">TEST</button>
    <md-spinner *ngIf="loggingin" style="margin: 30px auto"></md-spinner>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {
  loggingin = false;
  user: User = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    image: '',
    name: '',
    provider: '',
    uid: ''
  };
  signin = false;
  contact = false;
  isLinear = true;
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;



  constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private userS: UserService,
    private uis: UiService,
    private authS: MyAuthService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }


  test() {
    let newUser = new User (
      null,
      'XXXX',
      'XXXX'
    );
    console.log(newUser);
    this.authS.onSignin(newUser)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        localStorage.setItem('token', data['token']);
        localStorage.setItem('userId', data['userId']);
      })
  }


  onSignin(s: string) {
    this.loggingin = true;
    if (s === 'rent') {
      this.authS.onSignin(this.user)
        .subscribe(user => {
          localStorage.setItem('token', user['token']);
          localStorage.setItem('userId', user['userId']);
          this.userS.getUser()
            .subscribe(user => {
              if (user.needsToRate !== 0) {
                this.router.navigate(['/review']);
                this.uis.onFlash('Signed In Successfully', 'success');
                this.loggingin = false;
              } else if (!user.finishedTutorial) {
                this.router.navigate(['/tutorial']);
                this.uis.onFlash('Signed In Successfully', 'success');
                this.loggingin = false;
              } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                this.uis.onFlash('Signed In Successfully', 'success');
                this.loggingin = false;
              }
            }, resp => {
              console.log(resp);
            });
        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
          if (err.status === 404) {
            this.loggingin = false;
            this.uis.onFlash('Email Not Found', 'error');
          } else if (err.status === 401) {
            this.loggingin = false;
            this.uis.onFlash('Incorrect Username or Password', 'error');
          } else {
            this.loggingin = false;
            this.uis.onFlash('Error Signing In', 'error');
          }
        });
    } else {
      this.authS.authSignin(s)
        .subscribe( authUser => {
          this.authS.onAuthToken(authUser)
            .subscribe(token => {
              localStorage.setItem('token', token['token']);
              localStorage.setItem('userId', token['userId']);
              this.userS.getUser()
                .subscribe(user => {
                  if (user.needsToRate !== 0) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/review']);
                    this.uis.onFlash('Signed In Successfully', 'success');
                    this.loggingin = false;
                  } else if (!user.finishedTutorial) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/tutorial']);
                    this.uis.onFlash('Signed In Successfully', 'success');
                    this.loggingin = false;
                  } else {
                    this.loggingin = false;
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      location.reload();
                    },500);
                    this.uis.onFlash('Signed In Successfully', 'success');
                  }
                }, resp => {
                  console.log(resp);
                });
            }, error => {
              console.log(error);
              this.loggingin = false;
              this.uis.onFlash('Error Signing In', 'error');
            });
      })
    }
  }

}
```

*** UPDATE
I moved the signin button from inside the angular material md-step element to outside it and it worked fine. Not sure whats going on here but this seems to be the issue.

Here is the code from above causing the CORS problem on non chrome web browsers

```
<md-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" *ngIf="!loggingin" style="text-align: center; max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto">
            <md-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
              <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
                <ng-template mdStepLabel>Email</ng-template>
                <md-form-field>
                  <input mdInput placeholder="Enter Email" formControlName="firstCtrl" [(ngModel)]="user.email" required>
                </md-form-field>
                <div>
                  <button md-button mdStepperNext><p class="p2">NEXT</p></button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </md-step>
            <md-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
              <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
                <ng-template mdStepLabel>Password</ng-template>
                <md-form-field>
                  <input type="password" mdInput placeholder="Enter Password" formControlName="secondCtrl" [(ngModel)]="user.password" required>
                </md-form-field>
                <div>
                  <button md-button mdStepperPrevious><p class="p2">BACK</p></button>
                  <button md-button (click)="onSignin('rent')"><p class="p2">SIGNIN</p></button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </md-step>
          </md-horizontal-stepper>
```

Comment: What does your client-side code look like? Is your server-side code set up to respond to `OPTIONS` requests?

Comment: My client-side sends the options containing POST, GET, etc. and then executes. Ill upload some code. This is an odd error. I recently switched my app to use Angular Material for styling. It seems like the issue comes from using the md-step module? Ill upload some code but I tried the same request as a test button with the information hard-coded for login and it worked peferctly

Comment: Hi @JonathanCorrin I have same issue, I am using hapi.js at server side and reactjs app client side. Can you please tell me what have update in server side and client configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anyone having this issue with md-step or Stepper in google material. Try adding type="button" to each step. I find it odd I was receiving a CORS error but it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Jonathan answer seems correct. Apparently Apple decided that a html button is only a button if it has type="button" even the type=submit will throw the same error...

Comment: Yep.  Super lame.